# How to finetune a App Engine based on CPU and memory usage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

So we just got started using GCP App Engine and fired up two instances with flexible environment. We are hitting this app constantly on a 24x7 basis, when I check the CPU and memory usage, I see they are very low (1GB and about 3% CPU usage).

Does this mean that we have oversized our instance and we are paying too much? Can we scale down CPU/RAM to "see what happens"?

We are in a testing phase and we can afford to run into performance bottlenecks without disrupting service.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Level of control that is available over the resources, depends on the App Engine type:

1. For App Engine Standard it is [possible to set in the app.YAML file: instance_class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#instance_class), that is associated with [memory and cpu limit](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes).
2. For App Engine Flexible there are more options [to configure resources in the app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#resource-settings) file, but associated VM Instance can have more resources than specified. 
   It will depend on associated [machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types).

[App Engine Standard generates reports](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/managing-resources), about performance and resource utilization, that can be useful to decide what configuration is optimal for the app.